# Choose a div class inside a div class using jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup, html

```
<div class="main-banner">
<div class="row" style="height:298px;">



<div class="row" style="margin-top:40px;">
    <div class="seven columns">
        some other data,div and css blocks....
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</div>
</div>
```

To select the top div i can use

```
    Element title = doc.select("div.productTitle").first();
```

1. I need to select the 4th div (class='seven columns') and display the
   data in a `webview`, so what's the  syntax for that?
2. Inside another inner level div, there are some `<select> <options>`
   pairs.How can i get it into an `Array` using `jsoup`?

Answer (score 1):

I do not clearly understand your question. Could you be more specific? You know how to select a div, so why don't you?

```
Elements div = doc.select("div.ClassName");
```

If you have a structure that looks like this, and want to select the fourth one:

```
<div class="row">
    <div>Number one!</div>
    <div>Number two!</div>
    <div>Number three!</div>
    <div>Number four!</div>
    <div>Number five!</div>
</div>
```

You can use:

```
Element fourthDiv = doc.select("div.row div:eq(4)");
```

This way you can nest selections quite easily!

Comment: Thank you. But i have a structure like say                                   <div class="row">
<div class="pen">                                                         <div>Number one!</div>
    <div>Number two!</div>
    <div>Number three!</div>
    <div>Number four!</div>
    <div>Number five!</div>                                          </div>
</div> now the div 'pen' is inside the div 'row'.So how do i proceed to select the 4th div inside div='pen' which is inside div='row'? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use this site to get your syntax http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax and if you do not get your result let me know.. 
and here is an example how mto pasre data using jsoup

```
    public class ListShow extends Activity {
String url;
String DetailText;
TextView tv1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.srmcem.ac.in")
                .timeout(10000).get();

        Elements link = doc
                .select(".sidebar > ul > li > div > marquee > a[href]");
        String url1 = "";
        String text = "";
        String detail = "";
        for (Element element : link) {
            text = element.text();

            if (element != null) {
                url1 = element.absUrl("href");
            }
            detail += text + "\n" + url1 + "\n\n";
        }

        DetailText = detail.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    tv1.setText(DetailText);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[try.jsoup.org](http://try.jsoup.org/)** to help test and debug your HTML and selectors.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan Hedley , I got the problem resolved.I used google chrome developer  tool and  uwent through dom and jquery selector and  now i can pin point the data ,images that i need in my app.